# Store update not registered

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Might have the answer of why its happening but just wanted to double check.

I have the following store:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

function createData() {
  const { subscribe, set, update } = writable({
    "1": {
      name: "",
    },
    "2": {
      name: "",
    },
    "3": {
      name: "",
    },
  });

  return {
    subscribe,
    set,
    update,
    remove: (i) =>
      update((n) => {
        delete n[i];

        return n;
      }),
  };
}

export const data = createData();
```

Which is been used in the following way:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { data } from "./store.js";
 
  $: console.log($data)

  function save() {
    console.log($data);
  }
</script>

<div>
  <children>
    {#each Object.entries($data) as [key, d]}
      <child>
        {key}
        <input type="text" bind:value={d.name} />
        <button on:click={() => data.remove(key)}>delete</button>
      </child>
    {/each}
  </children>

  <button on:click={save}>Save</button>
</div>
```

Nothing too fancy - for each key in the store object create `input` and bind it to the `name` value and a button that deletes the current element (deleting works just fine). Single button (`Save`) which when pressed will console the current store state.

I was expecting that when typing in any of the `input` element the store will be updated and this will be registered by the `$: console.log($data)` statement.

What im seeing is that typing in the input elements do not trigger the top `$: console.log`. But when the `Save` button is pressed the content of the store is correct and it contains whatever values were written.

The image below shows the result. I was expecting to have 4 `Store updated` entries - one initial and 3 more for each input edit

[image: Result]

My guess is that this is happening because of the store structure and if the store was an array of elements, istead of an object with props, then each input entry will be registered.

Repl link: https://svelte.dev/repl/90b0b3c2f60a4cd480f8413ea812035a?version=4.2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `bind` directly to an object in the store, so `bind` will update the object directly, and not go through the store, so the store is never aware of that the value in the store has changed.

The solution is to bind to the object through the store, e.g. use:

```
bind:value={$data[key].name}
```

Comment: Ahh it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!